# Generic Bot – A Moderation Chatbot

Tags: app, script, chat, flags, chatbot

[Generic Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7481043/generic-bot) is a chatbot meant to help with moderation tasks on Stack Overflow. You can find the bot in the [SOBotics chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics).

---

### Flag Tracker (Userscript)

When you flag a post, this userscript will let you monitor that post and notify you in case the post gets edited.

If a post you flagged has been edited, you will be pinged by [@GenericBot](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/7481043/generic-bot). Make sure you're pingable in the [SOBotics chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) room to receive the notifications.

[image: flag tracker report screenshot]

#### Install

[view source](https://github.com/Floern/stackoverflow/blob/master/userscripts/flagtracker.user.js) | [direct link (install)](https://github.com/Floern/stackoverflow/blob/master/userscripts/flagtracker.user.js?raw=true)

#### Chat commands

Generic Bot provides the following commands to be used with this userscript:

- `@GenericBot untrack all` – Stop tracking all posts that you have flagged until now.
- reply `untrack that` – Stop tracking a specific post that was reported (reply to the report message).

---

### Review Monitor

Keeps track of the reviews in the review queues.

#### Chat commands

- `@GenericBot myreviews` – Compares your reviews in the Low Quality Post Review Queue to the community's results, providing a list of reviews where you disagreed with the community consensus.

[image: @GenericBot myreviews]

---

### Chatroom antifreeze

Posts a random message to a chatroom after 5 days of inactivity to avoid it getting frozen.

[image: antifreeze message]

**Note:** At the moment there is no command for this feature, I have to add it manually. Ping me in [SOBotics](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) if you want GenericBot to monitor a room.

Comment: This is a great tool! Helps notify if posts need to be reflagged for deletion, if they were prematurely edited out of the queue.

Comment: Any chance this wonderful tool could work for non-SO sites as well?

Comment: So the Flag Tracker is extremely useful, but would it be possible to make a userscript that can add an icon/something near the bottom of a post to untrack a post? There are sometimes times where I make a mistake, and it would be useful to have an easy way to untrack a post.

Comment: would it be a problem for you if I spread the word about the chatroom antifreeze feature? Since many people will ping you to add their chatrooms to the list

Comment: I came here reading [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70198/how-do-i-unfreeze-a-frozen-chat-room) for chat anti-freeze. Currently I have to remember coming after atleast once in 14 days and when I forget, luckily a kind user reminds me to do it (till yet that is) and yes I forget messaging on chat despite frequently visiting MSE. So, it would be great if you can add that "bot" on [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138744/chit-chat-with-ib). Also, I didn't find you on SOBotics so commenting here. Will delete this later if you wish.